# What are the drawbacks to hosting a git repository with WebDAV instead of SSH?

Tags: git, ssh, webdav, dreamhost

I have a large git repository that I am hosting with Dreamhost. It has grown slowly over time and have had no problems with it until just now. It has no problem pushing and pulling but when I try to clone from the remote the pack-objects process is getting a kill signal 9. From what I have read this is dreamhost killing the process because it is using to much memory.

There are work arounds (clone on the server and then download) but I am looking for a permanent solution. The repository will continue to grow.

Is WebDAV my best option and will everything work the way it does now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell all your really lose is hooks. Git treats the WebDAV the same way it would with SSH.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have collected too much garbage.  Can you run `git gc` on the remote server? (I'm betting you won't be able to)

If not, try downloading the bare repository (using tar or rsync), run `git gc` on it, and then upload it once again, overwriting the old one (make sure you have a back up of it, or up-to-date clone, just in case!).

If this fixes your problem (and I suspect it will), then try setting up a cron task to run `git gc` in your bare repo automatically.  Additionally, lowering the gc.auto config variable may help.  Try setting, in your bare repo, `git config gc.auto 3000`.

Comment: I do have shell access to the server. The problem is that if a process runs for too long or uses to much memory dreamhost will kill it.

That was the first thing I tried. It did shrink things down a little but not much. I have a cron job that runs `git gc` on all of the repositories on the server once a week so I wasn't expecting it to do much.